# Define an object as 'root' of module

Tags: python, python-import

I have a module `module.py`

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var='123'

    def printit(self):
        print self.var
```

And now I'm trying to import this module into `script.py` and call the method `printit` from the class `SomeClass`

```
import module

module.SomeClass().printit()
```

I also can do it by another way:

```
from module import SomeClass

SomeClass().printit()
```

And another one:

```
from module import SomeClass as module

module().printit()
```

It's nice but i want to get something like this:

```
import module

module().printit()
```

or even

```
import module

SomeClass().printit()
```

Generally I want to make a module that will export `SomeClass` by default. Is it possible to make something like this by changing `module.py`?

Comment: I suppose you could do `printit = SomeClass().printit`, but it's not at all clear why: 1. `printit` is an instance method of `SomeClass` if you want to use it standalone like this; or 2. why you think that last form, which magically introduces the variable `SomeClass` into the scope, is more readable.

Comment: Maybe `from module import SomeClass as module`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm beginning to understand that my example is little unsuccessful. Final purpose consist in importing `SomeClass` and calling his methods 1. shortly without `module.` 2. avoid the usage of `from .. import`, just simply `import module`.

Comment: But *why* do you want to do that? Python values readability, including being explicit in where the names in the current scope are coming from. If you could just `import foo` and suddenly `bar` was in scope, that wouldn't be terribly helpful. Just use `from module import SomeClass` (or, probably better` turn `printit` into a function and `import` that).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, i've found another failure of my example. The thing is that in my code I'am trying to import instance of class (yes, I should say so in the beginning, but there is no difference). Imported instance has the same name as my module file. And i wanna to `import mymodule` and call instance simply `mymodule.printit()` not `mymodule.mymodule.printit()`. That's why.

Comment: Then no, you can't do that. You either have to `import foo from bar` and use `bar` or `import foo` then use `foo.bar`.